# Adding a new column with data from a join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

What is the best approach to add a column to an existing table with values from a join...For example:

If I join Table A to Table B...

```
Select
A.Column1,
A.Column2,
B.Column1,
B.Column2,
B.Column3
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
ON A.Column1 = B.Column2
```

Basically I just want to copy the column that exists in Table B over to Table A, how can I add new A.Column3 to Table A to match B.Column3 based on the join?

Answer (score 38):

Try this:

```
alter table A add column3 datatype

update A 
set column3 = B.column3 
from A inner join B on A.Column1 = B.Column2
```

Comment: Using `from A inner join B` is *significantly* slower than a simple `from B where A.Column1 = B.Column2` clause on Postgres. (I'm not sure if the former works at all; it never completed for me.)

Comment: In SQLite I get the last row of the b table as my value for all rows using this method.

Answer (score 10):

Note that this is probably *not* most efficient method

```
alter table A add column3 [yourdatatype];

update A set column3 = (select column3 from B where A.Column1 = B.Column2) 
  where exists (select column3 from B where A.Column1 = B.Column2)
```

Answer (score 0):

First use an [*alter table*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx) command to add the new column.

Afterwords use *update* command to put the values of B in column created in A.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
alter A add column3 datatype;

update A
inner join (select column2 ,column3, count(*) as cnt from B group by column2) b
on A.column1 = b.column2 set 
A.column3 = b.column3;
```

Answer (score -3):

You can make a new table using INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO
   NEW_A
SELECT
   A.*,
   B.Column3
FROM A
   INNER JOIN B
   ON A.Column1 = B.Column2
```

Comment: he wants to add to an existing table.